# Break up a large CSV file

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv

I have a large CSV file (about 6,000 rows) that I want to break up into smaller CSV files (about 100 rows each). Is there an easy way to do that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**[CSV Splitter](http://www.fxfisherman.com/forums/forex-metatrader/tools-utilities/75-csv-splitter-divide-large-csv-files.html#post727)** is a handy tool that allows you to define the number of lines and maximum pieces of output files. It will split the CSV file according to what you have defined.

[image]

`1.` Fill in necessary information:

- CSV file: the path to the CSV that you wanted to split.
- Number of lines: the maximum number of lines/rows in each splitted piece (100 in your case).
- Max Pieces: limit the number of output files. '0' is unlimited.

`2.` Click **Split Now!** and that's it.

You will find the splitted pieces in a new folder of the same directory of the CSV file. By default, a folder {csv file name}_Pieces will be created and all of the output files will be stored under this folder. The output file format will be named as {csv file name}_1.csv, {csv file name}_2.csv, {csv file name}_3.csv and so on.