# What software to use to manage/transform a 10Gb csv file (100+ million lines)

Tags: csv

So I have this uge csv file with more than 100 million records and I want to work on. **I don't want to just edit it**.

What I need is to use some kind of excel / basic database transformations (group by, extract some caracters, add a new column based on combined info, etc.).

What is the best way to do this ? Import into a database ? (such as Oracle, quite sure Access cannot manage such big file) Are other tools usable ? At work I used to have a software called Amadea (http://www.isoft.fr/html/prod_amadea_en.htm) that did some data transformations like this. Don't know of any other (free) tools that does this the same way.

Thanks!

Comment: You could have a look at TALEND - powerful opensource ETL.http://www.talend.com/

Comment: have you considered splitting the file into multiple files?  Even if you were to import into a full database solution like MSSQL or MySQL you likely will need to split the data into multiple files.  Even a full database solution is going to have trouble trying to parse 10GB of data.  http://superuser.com/questions/98583/break-up-a-large-csv-file?rq=1

Comment: Splitting is not a good idea as I will know how to split only **after** calculations

Comment: I'm going for Talend, seems to do what I'm looking for. However, learning curve seems a bit steep...

Answer (score 2):

Definitely use a database. There are plenty of free ones, such as MySQL, or if you just want one computer to work on it at a time then Sqlite is extremely good.

Do check that your import has worked properly first, especially if there is non-ascii or large numbers in the input data set.