# Convert large PDFs to CSV

Tags: microsoft-excel, pdf, csv

I have some very large PDFs with comma separated text inside of them. I assume they are PDFs instead of CSV or XML because they were encrypted, but either way I've got the PDFs decrypted and I need to import them into a spreadsheet. The PDFs are some 75,000 pages large, 95 megabytes each.

I've tried numerous ways to convert them using online methods, using Adobe Acrobat, and even Excel. Each method takes issue with the PDFs being too large and cant handle it. I program for a living, so my next method might involve some actionscript to read a PDF if possible.

How can I convert these huge PDFs?

Comment: Are those PDFs also protected, or just the site is the issue?  If yes, then splitting them might help.

Comment: As far as I know they are not protected, but the issue with splitting them is the same issue as converting them: most programs just don't want to open it without crashing

Comment: 95MB should be nothing to Adobe Acrobat, and Adobe Acrobat supports converting to Word, once you do that you should be able use the solutions  described in the answers to this question: http://superuser.com/questions/98583/break-up-a-large-csv-file?rq=1

Comment: Are you sure they are PDFs?  The main purpose of a PDF is to preserve page layout and appearance; it makes no sense to use it with CSV data.  Also, to create PDF files so large that even Acrobat can't deal with them makes me question whether they are actually PDFs or what the intended purpose of using PDF might have been.  If Acrobat can't open it, it may be because it isn't a PDF, rather than the size.  If you can't even open the files, how do you know they are decrypted and what the contents look like?

Comment: @fixer1234 "The main purpose of a PDF is to preserve page layout and appearance; it makes no sense to use it with CSV data." preaching to the choir here. I have no control over the files I'm given. Blame the U.S. Government. Acrobat can open it, but converting doesnt work because it says it's too large and even Select All causes it to freeze up.

Comment: The US Government?  Say no more.  It all makes perfect sense now.  BTW, you could open it and then copy/paste in chunks, but 75,000 pages would get old pretty fast.  If you can view the contents and see that it's actually CSV data, an avenue to pursue might be your programming skills, and tools in one of the PDF toolkits.  Also, look at the raw file.  It's possible that the data is at least in big chunks and in a form where you could automate extraction.

Comment: @fixer1234 That's my plan if I can't get it working today. I've used AS3 to export PDFs, I'll just see if it's possible to read PDF text boxes, export to a text file, and remove the page numbers with regex. I'm hoping there's an easier way though